# htaccess file ignored over https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I'm trying to redirect https (https://example.com:8443) to http (http://example.com:8000), but my htaccess is ignored when accessing the website over https.

I've tested it by adding some gibberish to the htaccess file , the http version returns **ERROR 500** but the **https one is working fine.**

How do i make my secure local version take the htaccess file into account?
if it's not possible how do i redirect without using htaccess ?

Ps: i've looked for ALLOWOVERIDE in the httpd-ssl.conf but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config for SSL (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf by default), ensure that it looks something like:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

> The default for AllowOverride is 'None' (thats why you couldn't find it), so any other setting (such as
>   'All') which adds FileInfo capabilities is OK.

Comment: Adding this in httpd-ssl.conf File didn't fix it for me.

`<VirtualHost _default_:8443>
#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp7/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp7/htdocs">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>`
...

I appreciate your help.